# JQuery DataTables in ASP.NET MVC With A Query Source

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

**Summary**

I'm trying to replicate similar working technology I currently have in ColdFusion and do it in MVC 5.  I'm very new to ASP.NET, so I just have the beginning framework at this point.  I need assistance on getting this data.
What I currently do in ColdFusion is run a query in a CFC to populate a DataTable.  The CFC arranges the query results in JSON format and I pass that to the AJAX source of the DataTable.

So here is what I can do in ColdFusion.

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable( {
    //The CFC source of the data
    "ajax": 'cfc/DataTablesSource.cfc?method=exampleFunction', 
    "columns": [                                            
        {"data": "ID", "width": "20%"},
        {"data": "FIRST_NAME", "width": "40%"},
        {"data": "LAST_NAME", "width": "40%"}
    ]
});
```

**CFC (The source of the data)**

```
<cffunction name="exampleFunction" access="remote">

    <!---Query is run here--->
    <cfquery name="qSourceQuery">
        Select top 5 ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
        From Name
    </cfquery>

    <!---The rest of this arranges the data in JSON format--->

    <cfset data = [] />

    <cfoutput query="qSourceQuery">
        <cfset obj = {
            "ID" = ID,
            "FIRST_NAME" = FIRST_NAME,
            "LAST_NAME" = LAST_NAME
        } />

        <cfset arrayAppend(data, obj) />
    </cfoutput>

    <cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="Yes">
        <cfoutput>
            {"aaData":#serializeJSON(data)#}
        </cfoutput>
    </cfprocessingdirective>

    <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="No" showdebugoutput="No">
</cffunction>
```

**The JSON Result**

```
{"aaData":[
    {"FIRST_NAME":"James","ID":"000001","LAST_NAME":"Smith"},
    {"FIRST_NAME":"David","ID":"000003","LAST_NAME":"Aaronson"},
    {"FIRST_NAME":"Jim","ID":"000005","LAST_NAME":"Thompson"},
    {"FIRST_NAME":"Alan","ID":"000006","LAST_NAME":"Abbott"},
    {"FIRST_NAME":"Lawrence","ID":"000012","LAST_NAME":"Abbott"}
]}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id="tablediv">
    <div class="dataTables_wrapper">
        <table id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!---Data and tags are dynamically generated--->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MVC**

From this point I can replicate the creation of a DataTable if I provide the JSON data myself (actually there's tons of examples like that.)  However, I want the source of the table to be a query.  I need help doing that in MVC.

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable( {
    //New data source points to controller and action
    "ajax": '/TestPages/GetJSONMemberList', 
    "columns": [                                            
        {"data": "ID", "width": "20%"},
        {"data": "FIRST_NAME", "width": "40%"},
        {"data": "LAST_NAME", "width": "40%"}
    ]
});
```

**A Model What The Query Result Should Look Like**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApplication.Models
{
    public class MemberList
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
        public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The Action in the Controller**

```
public ActionResult getJSONMemberList()
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            aaData = new[]
                {
                    //Hard coded data here that I want to replace with query results
                    new MemberList { ID = "000001", FIRST_NAME = "James", LAST_NAME = "Smith" },
                    new MemberList { ID = "000003", FIRST_NAME = "David", LAST_NAME = "Aaronson" },
                    new MemberList { ID = "000005", FIRST_NAME = "Jim", LAST_NAME = "Thompson" }
                }
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id="tablediv">
    <div class="dataTables_wrapper">
        <table id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!---Data and tags are dynamically generated--->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Conclusion**

So in my new application, my Ajax source points to a controller action that creates a JSON formatted list of data.  I'm looking for advice on getting query data to that controller or to that model from SQL Server.  I'm using Entity Framework in this application, but I don't have to.  What would be the best way to replicate this?  Would this involve calling a stored procedure?  If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Entity Framework and LINQ, I was able to achieve this.

In my controller, I have this

```
//Used to connect to the Entities standing in for the database
private NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
```

This method will run a query that will return the JSON format needed.

```
public ActionResult getJSONQuery()
    {
                    //The table or entity I'm querying
        var query = db.Names
            .Where(p => p.ID > 1)
            .Select(p => new{p.ID, p.FIRST_NAME, p.LAST_NAME});

        return Json(new { aaData = query }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My initialization looks the same, and just points to the controller running the query.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable( {
    //New data source points to controller and action
    "ajax": '/TestPages/GetJSONQuery', 
    "columns": [                                            
        {"data": "ID", "width": "20%"},
        {"data": "FIRST_NAME", "width": "40%"},
        {"data": "LAST_NAME", "width": "40%"}
    ]
});
```

Comment: @madova, thank you for posting this. I am migrating a CF app to ASP.NET MVC with EF and DataTables and this was invaluable. Much appreciated!